# Bellman-Ford and some facts about Graph G?

Tags: math, graph, graph-theory, shortest-path, bellman-ford

We know the bellman-ford algorithms check all edges in each step, and for each edge if,

> d(v)>d(u)+w(u,v)

then d(v) being updated such that w(u,v) is the weight of edge (u, v) and d(u) is the length of best finding path for vertex `u`. if in one step we have no update for vertexes, the algorithms terminate. with supposing this algorithms, for finding all shortest path from vertex `s` in graph G with `n` vertex after `k<n` iterate is finished, which of the following is correct?

> 1) number of edges in all shortest paths from `s` is at most `k-1`
>
> 2) weight of all shortest paths from `s` is at most `k-1`
>
> 3) Graph has no negative cycle.

I'm sure one of these is True, but My TA says Two of these is correct. any idea or hint for these problem ?

Comment: This seems to be a bit too broad for Stack Overflow; perhaps it would be better suited to one of the [science SE sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#science)?

Comment: what !! too board? no, i dont think so.  @GoBusto

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through the statements one at a time:

> 1) number of edges in all shortest paths from `s` is at most `k-1`

Consider the following graph:

```
s ---e1---> n1 ---e2---> n2 ---e3---> n3
```

If the edges are ordered as given (`e1, e2, e3`), then you will have the correct distance for every node after the first iteration (checking `e1` updates `n1`, then checking `e2` updates `n2` and so on). So in this case, the algorithm stops after `k=2` iterations because the second iteration does not change anything. Number of edges in the longest shortest path is `3` and `3 <= 2-1` does not hold. Hence, this statement is wrong. If, however, all edges are evaluated simultaneously, then the statement is correct (every iteration can go only one edge farther away than the previous iteration).

> 2) weight of all shortest paths from `s` is at most `k-1`

Neither the number of edges nor their total weight is limited by `k-1`. Consider that all edges in the above example have weight 1000. It is obvious that there is no connection to `k`.

> 3) Graph has no negative cycle.

If you define the algorithm as you did (terminates when no changes are made), then this is correct. Any negative cycle would cause an infinite loop because the distances of vertices in this loop successively decrease.

Comment: The answer sheet says two of the sentence is correct. what do you mean by "however, all edges are evaluated simultaneously, then the statement is correct"

Comment: E.g. the checks are done in parallel in SIMD fashion. Or a copy of the old state is made and the checks are performed on that copy (which would be a waste of time and memory). Answer sheets are not necessarily correct.

Comment: is it possible more detail about " all edges are evaluated simultaneously"? would you please add an example for clarification ?

Comment: It just means a modification of the algorithm that parallelizes the inner loop. It can not be done trivially on a usual CPU and is irrelevant for the code you linked (p. 12). Furthermore, the code does not have the condition that the algorithm terminates when no changes are made (but after a constant number of iterations). Is that a modification of the task?

Comment: I found it on google. thanks. yes that algorithm run constant number and not when not changed.... yeah, you are right. but my misunderstanding point is why we have parallelism (1) is true.

Comment: If edge e2 is checked during one iteration of a parallelized version, it cannot access the results of the check for e1 in the same iteration (because the check for e1 is still being calculated). And this dependency within a single iteration is the reason why (1) does not hold.

Comment: wow, you means if we use parallelized version, (1) is correct, if we didnt use if's false?

Comment: Depends on the parallelization technique. But yes, it can become true.

Comment: so in general without some  parallelized version, it's false? +1.

Comment: So Sorry, if on each step we check one edge, then (1) is true? yes?

Comment: would you please provide an example for simultaneously checking ?